# How to start a .exe after a specific game closes with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, explorer

I have just did this code with a batch file that closes the windows process `explorer.exe`. It starts some other programs that help with stuttering and closing `explorer.exe` helps quite a bit.

Thing is to start the game, I need to open a launcher but I want to close the launcher when I start the game. The game is *fortnite*. In the code it ends `explorer.exe` but when I close *fortnite* (Not the launcher), I want `explorer.exe` to start up.

Code:

```
START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Epic Games"\Launcher\Portal\Binaries\Win32\EpicGamesLauncher.exe
START C:\Users\Yqmxh\Documents\Optimization(s)\TimerResolution.exe
START C:\Users\Yqmxh\Documents\Optimization(s)\"Mz Game Accelerator.lnk"
Taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
start /wait "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
exit
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Is not readable.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to kill `explorer.exe`?

Comment: @dpap Sorry, I was in a rush and had to go somewhere! Thanks to the person who fixed it!

Comment: @Tiw When closed, it reduces stutters & fps drops. The process name is "FortniteClient-Win64-Shipping.exe"

Comment: @GerhardBarnard When closed, it reduces stutters & fps drops. The process name is "FortniteClient-Win64-Shipping.exe"

Comment: Would it be an idea to do some loop with the ``FOR`` command which does: a.) retrieving tasklist.exe, b.) looking for "FortniteClient-Win64-Shipping.exe" in the output with ``FIND`` or ``FINDSTR`` and then c.) wait some time with a ``PING`` as described at https://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php ? Or would that consume too much cpu time?

Comment: @FlorianStraub I understand some of what you just said, but could you please explain in in simpler terms?

Comment: Will the `TimerResolution.exe` stays running when you play the game? And can it starts after `"Mz Game Accelerator.lnk"`?

Comment: Perhaps insert `pause` after the `taskkill` command. So, the script starts the game, the command prompt pauses, the game later ends, focus command prompt and press any key to start `explorer.exe` and finally the scripts exits.

Comment: @michael_heath Good Idea, I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much cpu time this consumes, but it would work at least:

```
:beginning
tasklist | FIND "FortniteClient-Win64"
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (ECHO process was found
ECHO now waiting for six seconds
PING localhost -n 6 >NUL
GOTO beginning
)
ECHO the EXE is not running anymore
explorer
```

Since I considered the FOR loop too complex, I settled with a GOTO, which I hope I won't get downvoted for ;)

I think it's pretty self-explaining, but feel free to ask, if I'm wrong.